# Semaphores System V - semop implementation

Tags: c, semaphore

As you can see in the semaphore System V documentation (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semop.2.html) there is a part that states the following:

> EXAMPLE
>
> The following code segment uses semop() to atomically wait for the
>          value of semaphore 0 to become zero, and then increment the semaphore
>          value by one.
>
> ```
>       struct sembuf sops[2];
>        int semid;
>
>       /* Code to set semid omitted */
>
>       sops[0].sem_num = 0;        /* Operate on semaphore 0 */
>       sops[0].sem_op = 0;         /* Wait for value to equal 0 */
>       sops[0].sem_flg = 0;
>
>       sops[1].sem_num = 0;        /* Operate on semaphore 0 */
>       sops[1].sem_op = 1;         /* Increment value by one */
>       sops[1].sem_flg = 0;
>
>       if (semop(semid, sops, 2) == -1) {
>           perror("semop");
>           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
>       }
> ```

After this example I have several questions:

1- Does `(semop(semid, sops, 2) == -1)` executes the 2 sops positions? sops[0] and sops[1]?

2- If so why does `sops[0].sem_op = 0;` Waits for value of the semid to equal 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- Does (semop(semid, sops, 2) == -1) executes the 2 sops positions? sops[0] and sops[1]?

It attempts to do so, yes.  That's what the `semop()` function *does*, and it has to run in order to return a value (which the example code then tests against -1).  Like many C functions, `semop()` returns -1 when it fails; in that case, for that function, you can rely on neither operation having been performed.  Otherwise, `semop()` returns 0, and in that case you can rely on both operations having been performed.

> 2- If so why does sops[0].sem_op = 0; Waits for value of the semid to equal 0?

Because that's what that value of the `sem_op` is defined to mean.  As the documentation that you yourself linked puts it:

> If `sem_op` is zero, the process must have read permission on the
>          semaphore set.  This is a "wait-for-zero" operation [...]